# How do I check the content of variables passed to a template file?

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

I enabled Twig debug and I tried to debug some custom fields. However, if I try this with `debug()` or `kint()`, my application always crashes. My PHP memory size is currently 512MB; I assume that should be enough.

I realise that `node` is a bit too much to debug, so I tried debugging a field as in `node.field_video`, but that didn't work out as well.

How do I check the content of variables passed to a template file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow [document](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates).

> To dump only the available variable keys use:

```
{{ dump(_context|keys) }}
```

In this case you can use:

```
{{ kint(node|keys) }}
```

Or you can follow [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211928/how-can-i-make-kint-load-faster-when-debugging-twig-templates)

> Create a /modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/config.php file and add /
>   modify the line $_kintSettings['maxLevels'] = 3; (by @mdrummond on
>   Slack)

**The best way**: install module [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and using twig function

`{{drupal_dump(node)}}` to dump variables.

Comment: Apparently, you can also do this in your local settings file without having to create a kint config file: `$GLOBALS['_kint_settings']['maxLevels'] = 3;`

Comment: @DannyEnglander – Unfortunately `$GLOBALS['_kint_settings']['maxLevels']` in settings.local.php is overwritten by the default value in /modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/config.php nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your fields are inside custom blocks, and you're trying to access those fields, the syntax is slightly different. You'll want to access them this way, with a kint statement inside your custom twig file:

```
{{ kint(_context) }}
```

Inside the _context array, I found my fields were then inside the content array. So in my case, I was looking for the value of field_caption - and that was available at

```
{{ _context.content.field_caption.0 }}
```

I hope that helps someone else save some time along the way!